# Concatenate multiple fields with seperator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table contains Address1, Address2, Address3 etc... where values can be null or empty.

I am constructing full address by concatenating these fields into one.

```
Select Column1, Column2, ISNULL(Address1,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2,'')+ ', ' + ISNULL(Address3,'') As FullAddress
from TableName
```

Issue is if the address1 is null, but it still append the ',' which I want to remove. So it end up like ', address2value'

Is there better way of doing this

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want a trailing or leading comma, you can do:

```
Select Column1, Column2,
       STUFF(COALESCE(', ' + Address1, '') + COALESCE(', ' + Address2, '') + COALESCE(', ' + Address3, ''),
             1, 2, '') As FullAddress
from TableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you have in mind?

```
Select  Column1, 
        Column2, 
        ISNULL(Address1+',','') + ISNULL(Address2+',','')+ISNULL(Address3,'') As FullAddress
from    TableName
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Yes but if Address3 is null, it will leave ',' at end of the address

Comment: You can use the following link to generate ascii art tables https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Answer (score 0):

If any address1 or  address2 or address3 contains Null, It will not add the separator

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, CONCAT_WS(',',IFNULL(Address1,NULL),IFNULL(Address2,NULL),IFNULL(Address3,NULL)) AS FullAddress
FROM TableName;
```